# C program to generate pseudolanguage - global 3D array is too large (segmentation fault)?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

I am supposed to write a program which prints a text in pseudo-English by parsing an existing English text and looking at the last two letters printed to determine what the next one will probably be (the first to are imagined as '.' and ' '). For that task, I came up with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

short characters[256][256][256];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    if(argc<2){
        printf("In addition to the input file and maybe output file, please enter the number of output sentences as a command line argument.\n");
        return 1;
        }

    /*Different approach where I malloced the array instead, same result*/
    /*short ***characters=malloc(256 * sizeof(short**));
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
        *characters[i]=malloc(256 * sizeof(short*));
        for(int i2=0; i2<256; i++){
            characters[i][i2]=malloc(256 * sizeof(short**));
            }
        }*/

    /*Read text*/
    char a='.', /*pre-previous character*/
    b=' ', /*previous character*/
    c; /*current character*/
    int n=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        characters[a][b][c]++;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        n++;
        }

    /*Check how many sentences should be printed*/
    int sentences=0, multiplier=1;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(argv[1])/8; i++){
        sentences+=argv[1][i]*multiplier;
        multiplier*=10;
        }

    /*Print text*/
    int currentsentences=0, random, p1, p2;
    a='.';
    b=' ';
    while(currentsentences<sentences){
        int uninitialized;
        srand(time(0)+p1+p2+uninitialized); /*adds a bit of entropy*/
        random=rand()%n;
        p1=0;
        for(int i=0; ; i++){
            p2=p1+characters[a][b][i];
            if(random>p1 && random<=p2){
                c=characters[a][b][i];
                p1+=characters[a][b][i];
                break;
                }
            }
        putchar(c);
        if(c=='.' || c=='?' || c=='!')
            currentsentences++;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

It compiles without errors or warnings, however, when I try to run this program, it always returns a segfault before printing anything, unless I do not enter enough command line arguments, in which case it enters the first if clause. This is why I think it has to do something with the 3D array, as it seems not being able to even enter the first loop (if I let it print something before that, it won't). It is needed to be that large, as the structure is the following: `[pre-previous letter][previous letter][current letter]=how often did this constellation occur`. As I probably would not need higher ASCII and the range of `char` would probably have been enough, I tried `char` instead of `short` and an array of 128*128*128 - same result. Running it as root did not change much and the same goes for increasing `ulimit`. However, aren't global variabloes saved in the heap? The use of `malloc()`, which I commented out above, did not change anything as well. I have tried this on two machines, one OS: X, 64 Bit and 8GB DDR3, the other one Linux Mint 19.1, 64 Bit and 32GB DDR4. Both the same result, again (MacOS said `segmentation fault: 11`, Linux said `segmentation fault (core dumped)`). As the used memory of that array is about 33 MB, my RAM cannot be the problem either. So why is there a segfault? Do I need to allocate more RAM to the heap (I do not think this is even possible)? Is it maybe something that has not to do with the array and/or its size as all?

This is the latest version of the program; still showing the same behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

short characters[256][256][256];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   

    /*Check if number of sentences was given*/
    if(argc<2){
        printf("In addition to the input file and maybe output file, please enter the number of output sentences as a command line argument.\n");
        return 1;
        }

    /*Different approach with malloc*/
    /*short ***characters=malloc(256 * sizeof(short**));
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
        *characters[i]=malloc(256 * sizeof(short*));
        for(int i2=0; i2<256; i++){
            characters[i][i2]=malloc(256 * sizeof(short**));
            }
        }*/

    /*Read input text*/
    int a='.', /*pre-previous character*/
    b=' ', /*previous character*/
    c; /*current character*/
    int n=0;
    for(; (c=getchar())!=EOF; n++){
        characters[a][b][c]++;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        }

    /*Check how many sentences should be printed*/
    int sentences=0, multiplier=1;
    for(int i=strlen(argv[1])-1; i>=0; i--){
        sentences+=(argv[1][i]-'0')*multiplier;
        multiplier*=10;
        }

    /*Print text*/
    int currentsentences=0, random, p1=0, p2=0;
    a='.';
    b=' ';
    srand(time(0));
    while(currentsentences<sentences){
        random=(rand()+p1+p2)%n;
        p1=0;
        for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
            p2=p1+characters[a][b][i]; /*Determine range for character*/
            if(random>p1 && random<=p2){ /*Cheack if random number is in range of character*/
                c=characters[a][b][i];
                p1+=characters[a][b][i];
                break;
                }
            }
        putchar(c);
        if(c=='.' || c=='?' || c=='!')
            currentsentences++;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

UPDATE: An interesting behavior it shows is that, if you add something like `printf(„here“)` to the very beginning of the of the program, it will output that `„here“` if the first `if` statement if entered. However, if it is not, the program will return a segfault before printing anything.

UPDATE 2: Interestingly, if you do not give an input file and enter everything manually, it will not return a segfault, but also never finish as well.

UPDATE 3: The program now works, see below. Sorry for all the problems I  caused and thank you for helping me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int characters[128][128][128];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
     /*Check if input file was given*/
    if(argc<2){
        printf("Please enter an input file as command line argument.\n");
        return 1;
            }

    /*Check for input file, open it*/
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Error 404: Input file not found.\n");
        return 404;
        }

    /*Read input text*/
    int a='.';  /*pre-previous character*/
    int b=' ';  /*previous character*/
    int c;      /*current character*/

    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        if(c<127 && c>='\t'){ /*All characters from higher ASCII and system codes ignored. Still uses letters, digits and typical special characters and formatting characters.*/ 
            characters[a][b][c]++;
            a=b;
            b=c;
            }
        }
    fclose(fp);

    /*Check how many sentences should be printed*/
    unsigned int sentences;
    printf("How many sentences do you want to be printed? ");
    scanf("%d", &sentences);

    /*Print text*/
    unsigned int currentsentences=0, random, p1=0, p2=0, n;
    a='.';
    b=' ';
    srand(time(0));
    while(currentsentences<sentences){
        n=0;
        for(int i='\t'; i<127; i++){
            n+=characters[a][b][i];
            }
        random=(rand()+p1+p2+sentences+currentsentences+clock())%n;
        p1=0;
        for(int i='\t'; i<127; i++){    
            p2=p1+characters[a][b][i]; /*Determine range for character in combination with line 58*/
            if(random>=p1 && random<p2 && characters[a][b][i]!=0){ /*Check if random number is in range of character and that character occured in that combination*/
                c=i;
                printf("%c", c);
                characters[a][b][c]++; /*Experimental, language will change over time pseudo-randomly*/
                break;
                }
            p1+=characters[a][b][i];
            }
        if(c=='.' || c=='?' || c=='!')
            currentsentences++;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193282/discussion-on-question-by-fantasycookie17-c-program-to-generate-pseudolanguage).

Comment: `strlen(argv[1])-1` is faulty. `strlen` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned, so subtracting one from the length of a zero-length string will produce a large number, causing the loop to overrun the argument.

Comment: `argv[1][i]-49` is faulty. Hard-coded character codes should not be used, and 49 is not the code for 0 in any common C implementation. `argv[1][i] - '0'` would be correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There will not be a zero-string, or the program was used wrong. I believe one ASCII table said it was 49 (which seems to be wrong, as it is rather 48), so I changed that now.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: Users use programs wrong. That is pretty much their primary job. Good programs need to detect erroneous input and deal with it (printing an error message and terminating is sufficient) or at least tolerate it without failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire logic for selecting the next character is wrong:

- After the loop iterating `i` to examine `characters[a][b][i]`, the code sends `c` to output. At that point, `c` is either left over from some previous code or is `characters[a][b][i]` for some `i`, which means it is a count of triples that were seen during analysis—it is not a code for the character that should be printed.
- The code for preparing `p1` and `p2` and comparing them to a random number is nonsensical. The code ought to pick a random number in [0, *N*), where *N* is the sum of `characters[a][b][i]` for all character codes `i` and then select the character code `c` such that `c` is in [`p1`, `p2`), where `p1` is the sum of `characters[a][b][i]` for 0 ≤ `i` < `c` and `p2` is `p1 + characters[a][b][c]`.

Comment: The condition will be satisfied. It is meant to choose the character based on the probability. As for the first part, you are right. I changed it to this: `/*Check how many sentences should be printed*/
 int sentences=0, multiplier=1;
 for(int i=strlen(argv[1]); i>=0; i--){
  sentences+=argv[1][i]*multiplier;
  multiplier*=10;
  }`

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: That code is still wrong. `i=strlen(argv[1])` starts `i` pointing to the null character that terminates the string. It should point to the last character before the terminator. And `argv[1][i]` is the **code** for the character; it is not the **value** of a digit. (E.g., it is 48-57 for 0-9; but you want 0-9 for 0-9.) You **must** subtract the code for the 0 character to adjust the character code.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: And, no, the condition is not guaranteed to be satisfied.

Comment: There is a boundary check and I also edited that loop you spoke of so it works. However, the segfault seems to happen earlier.

Comment: Well, that first point is true. I now changed it to `c=i`. As for the second point: Thank you, but I know what my program does (at least I think so), and why should this be nonsensical? I think it is just fine for picking a letter in an array with a certain probability. But please, if you know a mUch better solution, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: The answer contains a correct solution. The existing code is wrong to use `n` in generating the random number. `n` is the total number of characters read from input. As written in this answer, the proper number to use is the sum of `characters[a][b][i]` for all character codes `i`.

Comment: Oh now I see. What you said is actually less than the total number of characters read as there are other places than just `characters[a][b]`. So I was wrong.

Comment: That fixed the segfault for some reason. Only problem left is that `random` may be 0 - and then the only thing it prints is probably `'\0'`, which is a problem, of course. I think I'll just do something so `random` is not 0. Maybe `sleep()` and then `srand(time(0))` or so... Well, that was not my question. I'll post the fixed code under the rest later so everyone can see it and StackOverflow stays that free platform of information.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: The fact that `random` can be zero is why I wrote to use [`p1`, `p2`), which is the interval that includes `p1` but excludes `p2`. When `random` is zero, that will select the first non-zero item in `characters[a][b][i]`. The current code is `random>p1 && random<=p2`, which tests for (`p1`, `p2`], which is wrong since it excludes `p1` and includes `p2`. (And of course the generation of `random` with `(rand()+p1+p2)%n` is wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is in this part of the code:

```
    p1=0;
    for(int i=0; ; i++){
        p2=p1+characters[a][b][i];
        if(random>p1 && random<=p2){
            c=characters[a][b][i];
            p1+=characters[a][b][i];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here you keep incrementing `i` without checking for out of bounds access. You should have something like:

```
if (i >= 255) { // error handling ....};
```

Also notice that `p1` in the loop is always zero.

In this part

```
random=(rand()+p1+p2)%n;
```

`p1` and `p2` is uninitialized so you may end up with a negative number which obviously means that you never hit the break statement. In other words - an endless loop where you keep incrementing `i` (which leads to out of bounds access).

As an example I changed the code like:

```
    for(int i=0; ; i++){
        printf("random=%d p1=%d a=%c b=%c i=%d", random, p1, a, b, i);
```

and got output like:

```
...
random=-3 p1=0 a=. b=  i=42484 p2=0
random=-3 p1=0 a=. b=  i=42485 p2=0
random=-3 p1=0 a=. b=  i=42486 p2=0
random=-3 p1=0 a=. b=  i=42487 p2=0
...
```

Notice that `random` is negative so the loop can never terminate.

Comment: I do not think there needs to be a boundary check. Look at the way how ’p1’ and ‘p2‘ are generated. ’n’ is the total number of letters.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17 well, try it out and you see. Just print the value of `i`

Comment: Did that, still segfault.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17 Did what? Initialized p1 and p2? Added check for `i` being < 256? Or?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear enough. I did both (look at the latest version of the code).

Answer (score 3):

Warnings, Errors and some very good suggestions are pointed out in the comments under your post. *nota bene*.

The following comment statement seems clear enough,

```
/*Check how many sentences should be printed*/
```

but it was not clear to me what was being done in the following snippet of your code to accomplish that:

```
    int sentences=0, multiplier=1;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(argv[1])/8; i++){  
        sentences+=argv[1][i]*multiplier;
        multiplier*=10;
        }
```

So the following short snippet is a suggestion for a different approach:

```
// assume at minimum input of one legal filespec,  
// eg: .\\filename.txt (Windows) or ./filename.txt (Linux)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int c = 0;
    int sentences = 0;

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Minimum command line usage:  <name>.exe [pathFileName].  Program exiting.");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp); 
        while(c) // will exit upon EOF (-1) Note c is int, not char
        {
            if( (c=='.') || (c=='?') || (c=='!') )
            {
                sentences++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else return 0;  //error, file not opened.

    /* rest of your code here */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think opening the input file the way you did worked better - the segfault now happens later in the program. I then can ask for the number of sentences with `scanf`.